# Can I install glib 2.30 on 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, glib

Can I install [glib](https://launchpad.net/glib/+packages) >= 2.30 on Ubuntu 11.04?

I mean [this package](https://launchpad.net/debian/sid/+source/glib2.0/2.30.2-6) from above link

Answer (score 3):

It wont work :(
As no one commented I thought to go in this adventure. I had 2 packages wanting this glib version, and I'll mention popular one - Gimp 2.7.4

I managed to find deb packages in Debian testing, and managed to replace glib 2.28 by making local temporary repository

After this I launch gimp `./configure`, and now it needs newer version of gtk+, then it needs newer version of pango, which needs even newer version of glib - 2.32, and I already messed enough with 2.30. I rebooted

...that's not all. Now I can't login, it simply displays logon screen and stays forever. I go to netroot recovery console, but have no Internet. I boot in Windows and download glib 2.28, then I installed this with aptitude and reboot when famous error pops - no permissions for .ICEauthority, so I can't login still. Booting in Windows and searching showed me that this error is everywhere with all kind of solutions, some of which I tried without success, like deleting file, changing various permissions and similar, until I installed `gnome-session` package, which was mentioned as last comment on askfedora I think.

That's it. Now back on track and thought to share this.

Cheers