# How to install GIMP 2.8 on 11.04?

Tags: installation, gimp

I've tried

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gimp
```

but, This isn't working.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What went wrong?

Comment: ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp contains only packages for 11.10 and 12.04 (none for 11.04)

Comment: where can i find packages for 11.04 ?

Comment: I searched around a bit and I found out that you can't install GIMP 2.8 on 11.04

Comment: It's not possible, because you'll need at least glib >= 2.30 which will brake your distribution, more: http://askubuntu.com/questions/105247/can-i-install-glib-2-30-on-ubuntu-11-04

Comment: Gimp 2.7.3 is as far as you can go with 11.04

Comment: ok, thanks a lot
think about updating to 11.10...